# iOS: Is a Distribution build supposed to work on my Developer device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am confused with profiles and certificates for the build I am trying to put on the Appstore.
In developer.apple.com/ I have properly created both a developer and distribution certificate. they are both linked to the single app I have created.
I have registered my device (iphone)
I also have properly created 1 development provisioning profile and 1 distribution provisioning profile.

When I build with dev certificate + dev provisioning profile: app works fine on my device
But I know the build needs a distribution certif and provisioning profile in order to get approved on the appstore.
However when I build with distribution certificate + distribution provisioning profile, the build is succesful, but I can't launch the app on my iphone, other iphone (with http://www.diawi.com/ or iTunes). It immediately crashes with the infamous error popup: "unable to download. "XXX" could not be installed at this time".
When I look at the device's log from Xcode, it clearly states the crash comes from a profile issue.

Is the distribution build supposed to work on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can check you Beta release build to your developer device using 'Apple Ad Hoc Distribution profile/certificat'. Here are Apple Dev link [Beta Testing Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: please mark my answer with RIGHT mark if it help-full your query.

Answer (score 0):

No. A distribution build will not just be installable on your device. You are meant to submit it to iTunes Connect from Xcode, where you build it from an archive, or from Application Launcher where you would submit it as an IPA.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for answering, so you can confirm it is normal that I can't launch it from my device?

Comment: It's 100 percent normal and you have nothing to worry about. When you submit your app from Xcode it will do lots of authorisation on your app and verify it's built the way it's meant to be.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming Gary, I will upload and submit (and cross my fingers). Let's see how it goes!

Comment: No worries. Once confirmed, you should mark that as the correct answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

you should have created adhoc distributed provisioning profile and add your device to that profile.

But you need iTunes Connect to submit the app to App Store. This time you can create provisioning profile for app store.

Advantages of iTunesConnect.
 1. You need not to add new device to the provisioning profile every
    time you want to test the app in new device.
 2. You can add as many as new test users to the app and can mark them as internal and external users.
 3. You can upload as many builds as you want and test those builds.